# Rebind keys in Spacemacs for NeoTree buffer

Tags: emacs, spacemacs

I want to rebind movement keys in NeoTree buffer in Spacemacs. Looking at my other key bindings in `dotspacemacs/user-config` this should work:

```
(with-eval-after-load 'neotree
  (evil-define-key 'normal neotree-mode-map (kbd "i") 'neotree-previous-line)
  (evil-define-key 'normal neotree-mode-map (kbd "k") 'neotree-next-line))
```

but as far as I can see it does nothing. How should one do this? I wouldn't mind vanilla Emacs solution, but I'm more interested how Spacemacs binds keys. Thanks...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This answer is thanks to [bmag](https://github.com/syl20bnr/spacemacs/issues/4042#issuecomment-269226265) at Github:

```
(with-eval-after-load 'neotree
  (evil-define-key 'evilified neotree-mode-map (kbd "i") 'neotree-previous-line)
  (evil-define-key 'evilified neotree-mode-map (kbd "k") 'neotree-next-line))
```